# Spectrum of a Banach algebra VS spectrum of a $C^*$-algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

The spectrum of a $C^*$-algebra  $A$ is the set of unitary equivalence classes of irreducible $*$-representations of $A$.

The spectrum of a unital commuative Banach algebra $B$ is the set of homomorphisms from $A$ to $\Bbb C$.

When we consider the Banach algebra, the definition of spectrum is different from the spectrum of a $C^*$-algebra. Can we define the spectrum of a Bannach algebra  $B$ as the set of unitary equivalence classes of representations of $B$?

Comment: How do you define a representation of a Banach algebra?

Comment: Can we have a result of GNS construction in the context of Banach algebras?